# Cannot award bounty less then previous bounty

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

I have tried setting a bounty on a question:

[Ferry connection between Crimea - Kerch and Georgia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21879/ferry-connection-between-crimea-kerch-and-georgia)

Originally set to 400.  Unfortunately I was not able to award it before it exprired.  I understand that I can't get the reputation back, which is not an issue.  The thing is that I can only award bounty that is higher then the one I tried awarding before, so the only bounty I can offer after the previous one expired, so the only bounty I can award now is 500 rep points.

This seems a little odd to me since I might just re-award the same rep amount or possibly less depending on the quality of the answers but the system doesn't allow me to.

Can someone clarify this point?

Comment: That prevents from keeing questions in the featured queue forever - only spending 50 rep for it every time.

Comment: That's how bounties work. See the **Can I offer a second bounty after the first one has expired?** sub-section in the linked dupe.